# How do I update a list item after adding it with Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online

I can't figure out how to do a very simple update of a column value in Power Automate in SharePoint online. I've seen examples of how to update an item on another list, but nothing that updates a value on the same item that was just added and triggered the workflow. Can anybody give me an example and maybe a very brief explanation?

I want to multiply the values of two columns and add it to a third column on the same item which will be blank. I used the formula to update the column I want using values from other columns. =[Dollar Amount]*[% Chance] but it says invalid syntax. There seems to be nothing intuitive in this new power automation and it's a horrible failure compared to how easy it used to be. MS is always making these mistakes.

Comment: Is `=[Dollar Amount]*[% Chance]` what you put into the field?

Comment: Yes. Those two column values are what I would like to use to set the third one. I also tried making a calculated column and using that value to set the empty field, but the calculated column does not show up under dynamic content

Comment: If you create a calculated column, of course that does not show in the edit interface. That's the point of a calculated column. It gets calculated by the formula in the column definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method, you could use a calculated column.

```
=[% Chance]*[Dollar Amount]
```

Second method，use Flow.
[image]
Test result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's Power Automate, not power automation. Details matter.

First, try to set the column value when you create the item. Then you won't have to edit it. If you already know the values for [Dollar amount] and [% Chance]  (Chance, really? Or Change?), then you can use these to generate the value before you create the item. You can do that in a variable or with a Compose action. Then create the item and refer to the variable or the Output of the compose action.

If this is not an option, you can use the Edit Item action and get the ID for the item from the action above that you used to create the item.

You say "MS is always making these mistakes." - It's more likely that the problem is a mismatch of data types, e.g. using text fields in calculations, or typos, or wrong syntax. That's not a mistake made by MS. Again, details matter.

**Edit after comments**: If the workflow is triggered by an item getting created, then you can use an Edit Item action and refer to the ID from the trigger item.

Comment: I tried creating a calculated column to solve the problem, then using this as the value for the empty column that I want to give a valueto, but the calculated column value does not show up under dynamic content

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because calculated columns can't have totals, So I have to create a number field and use the workflow to fill the calculated value into the number field for totaling.

Comment: There is no item being created in the workflow, it is only editing the item just added. I am using update list item action

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't understand what you want to achieve regarding "field totaling". Are you trying to sum a column for all items? SharePoint does not have that functionality and in Power Automate you would have to loop through all items and add the numbers. But when another item is added, that calculated total would be wrong. Please step back and explain the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to sum the values for a total for the calculated column, like I do with other numeric columns, but you can't do that with a calculated column. So I want the value of the calculated column to be added to a numeric column of the same item when the item is created, so that there is a total for the numeric column.