# How to create automatic numberng of a sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint

I have used one of Microsoft's templates to create a unique sharepoint list.  One of the columns is labeled priority.  The issue is that when a priority changes, I have to go in and manually update the other priority numbers.  This is a work-related SharePoint site and it would be useful if the priority column could be automatically updated if a priority changes.  I also am using Power Automate to send out notifications if a priority changes, so it can be tracked.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Power Automate to send notification, all you need to do is to add a new action `Update item` to update the priority number based on your requirements. As I am not sure about the pattern of the priority number, only a general example of updating list item via Power Automate here.
[How do I update a list item after adding it with Power Automate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882286/how-do-i-update-a-list-item-after-adding-it-with-power-automate)

Let me know if you need more help.